# Exchange 2003 - What would make the future free/busy calendar show for some users, but not others?

Tags: exchange-2003, calendar

I have a question similar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/132133/exchange-2003-calendars-far-future-is-blank-when-scheduling).  However, I have a problem with my Exchange 2003/Outlook 2010 environment where some users future availability doesn't show, while others do.

[image]

My Outlook is set up to publish 2 months of Free/Busy. This is configured in GPO.  However, as you can see from the image, 12/1/2014 is not 2 months away from today (10/21/2014) and yet, the schedule is unavailable for one of the users.  I have other examples of this for multiple users, and it seems to be random.

I have multiple Exchange 2003 back-end servers and one Exchange 2003 front-end server. All my public folders are located in one back-end server, specifically created just for public folders and the free/busy system folder.  Some users are on different servers, while others are on the same servers.  The users who I can't see future availability for is consistent for other users as well.

Has anyone come across a problem like this?  What would make the free/busy calendar show for some users, but not others, for anything over 8 weeks?

**UPDATE**

If I open the user's calendar to view, it shows me the free/busy calendar.  This issue only comes up if I go to schedule using the scheduling view.

Comment: Try this switch on the client side first: `outlook.exe /cleanfreebusy`.  As a final resort you can purposely remove the free/busy system folders from the server and recreate them following this article: http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;284200 -- but I'd start with that switch and also check OWA to see if free/busy works there.

Comment: `outlook.exe /cleanfreebusy` didn't make a change.  I'll try recreating the system folder later today.

Comment: The document you linked to is for if the Free/Busy Folder is missing.  Mine is not missing.  It's homed to the server I want it to be from, and the SiteFolderServer attribute is pointing to the right distinguishedName.  Is there a way to delete and recreate it?